# Get differences for each value from two row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

so i have this [query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49452003/laravel-join-with-only-limiting-2-row/49454980#49454980) that group `company` and find the latest two row from periods for each company from the `salesreport`

```
App\salesreport::join(DB::RAW('(SELECT company_id, GROUP_CONCAT(periods ORDER BY periods DESC) grouped_periods FROM salesreport GROUP BY company_id ) latest_report'),function($join){
        $join->on('salesreport.company_id','=','latest_report.company_id');
        $join->whereBetween(DB::raw('FIND_IN_SET(`salesreport`.`periods`, `latest_report`.`grouped_periods`)'), [1, 2]);
    })->get();
```

and its returning table that looks like this

```
+----+------------+-------+------------+
| id | company_id | value |  periods   |
+----+------------+-------+------------+
|  1 | A1         |   100 | 2017-02-02 |  
|  2 | A1         |   150 | 2017-01-01 |  
|  3 | A2         |    80 | 2017-06-01 |  
|  4 | A2         |    60 | 2017-04-01 | 
+----+------------+-------+------------+
```

and for the next step i want to find a differences for each value (which in this simple example is only value column but the real project is containing a lot of column

to make it to be something like this table

```
+----+------------+-----------+------------+
| id | company_id |   value   |  periods   |
+----+------------+-----------+------------+
|  1 | A1         | 100 (-50) | 2017-02-02 |
|  3 | A2         | 80 (+20)  | 2017-06-01 |
+----+------------+-----------+------------+
```

how to do that? is it possible in one request to the database? as i think we already got the data on hand but need to find a elegant way to do calculation between first row and second row for each company group within the sales report and turn it into some new fields

so maybe something like

```
App\salesreport::join(DB::RAW('(SELECT company_id, GROUP_CONCAT(periods ORDER BY periods DESC) grouped_periods FROM salesreport GROUP BY company_id ) latest_report'),function($join){
        $join->on('salesreport.company_id','=','latest_report.company_id');
        $join->whereBetween(DB::raw('FIND_IN_SET(`salesreport`.`periods`, `latest_report`.`grouped_periods`)'), [1, 2]);
    })->addSelect([DB::raw('(row1.value - row2.value) as row_differences')])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible (but probably not a good idea):

```
App\salesreport::join(DB::RAW('(SELECT company_id, MAX(periods) AS max_periods FROM salesreport GROUP BY company_id ) latest_report'),function($join){
    $join->on('salesreport.company_id','=','latest_report.company_id');
    $join->on('salesreport.periods','=','latest_report.max_periods');
})->select('*')->selectRaw(
    'CAST(`value` AS SIGNED)-CAST((
        SELECT `value`
        FROM `salesreport`
        WHERE `company_id`=`latest_report`.`company_id`
        ORDER BY `periods` DESC
        LIMIT 1,1
    ) AS SIGNED) as `difference`'
)->get();
```

If the `value` column is `SIGNED`, you can remove the casting.

Comment: hmmm weird, i just got the difference is not match with manual calculation, i tried to calculate manualy value in first periods and second periods and get the wrong number

Comment: Does it work with the example data from your question?

Comment: What result do you get?